# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() intermittently fails to return files even though folder has them

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .NET 4.0 to build a Windows Service application running on Windows Server 2008.  I use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` to get an array of `FileInfo` objects for the files in a folder on another Windows Server 2008 server on the network. There are always files matching the file mask in this folder.

The code runs once daily, and typically finds and processes all the files there. However, about every 3 or 4 (sometimes 5) days it returns without finding any files at all. If I re-run the code right away, it finds all the files as usual. (If don't manually re-run it but wait until the code runs again at its usual time the next day, it succeeds. Also, I've never seen it return only some of the files -- it's either all or none.)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("\\server\sourcefolder");
if (di.Exists)
{
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.ext", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    if (files.Count() == 0)
    {
        // WRITE AN ERROR WARNING ENTRY IN THE EVENT LOG
    }
    else
    {
        // DO PROCESSING HERE
    }
}
else
{
    // WRITE AN ERROR WARNING ENTRY IN THE EVENT LOG
}
```

Note: Initially, I wasn't checking to see if the folder existed or that there were actually any files returned.  The attempt to process the files obviously failed. Adding code to check those conditions allowed me to identify that the problem was `GetFiles()` sometimes not returning any files.

What could be the cause of this intermittent failure of `GetFiles()` to return any files in the folder?

Comment: Are absolutely sure those .ext files are *there* when the issue occurs? Sounds like a typical "Application X puts files there, your services processes and possibly removes them" process. Are you sure Application X has run before your service does and not a split second later, etc?

Comment: Maybe that's because you are look up in network. I'm not sure. To make sure, check it out with a local path.

Comment: Which account does your service use (LocalSystem, Administrator, ...)? And does that account have access to \\server\sourcefolder ?

Comment: Are these real machines or virtual machines?

Comment: The files are absolutely there.  The are deposited there by a different process but not removed (except by a cleanup process running once monthly and not at the same time as this code).

Comment: Other answers:
 - The account is a special service account that has full control privileges on the sourcefolder it's trying to look at.
  - The machines are both virtual machines on different hosts in different locations in the US.  Is that a possible known reason why this might fail intermittently?

Comment: The machines being virtual machines in principle shouldn't be a problem, but I have experienced cases where one virtual machine on a very heavily loaded host (other virtual machines stealing all the cpu time) was not getting dispatched enough to respond to some network I/O. Someone with more knowledge of monitoring virtual machine responsiveness as seen by the virtual machine hypervisor or whatever can perhaps answer that question. Worst case is an improperly configured setup where the virtual machine can be put to "sleep" for a while.